# How do I start KDE after X crash?

Tags: 10.04, kde

X just crashed on my Ubuntu 10.04 computer. GNOME is working, but I would like to use KDE instead. Running

```
startx
```

just starts GNOME, loging out through GNOME brings me back to the shell. I tried

```
sudo kdm
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run `startx` directly, instead use the startup scripts:

```
sudo start kdm
```

For Gnome, you would use:

```
sudo start gdm
```

For reference, equivalents of these command would be:

```
sudo service start kdm
sudo /etc/init.d/kdm start
```

(to be exact, the first is actually a wrapper which calls the new Upstart script)